# Is this simplified flow chart of how the ubuntu fire up is correct ?

Tags: boot, bootloader

I am trying to understand the way that Ubuntu starts what is being runned or started. Can you please confirm if my simplified flow chart is correct ?

[image]

1. First we power on a computer with linux distribution for instance : ubuntu by clicking on On
2. The BIOS is started from the ROM. It initializes the hardware.
3. The MBR is executed.
4. the boot loader loads the OS kernel.
5. The OS Kernel loads the Desktop User Interface.

I am a bit lost...

Comment: For a simplified flowchart, I'd say yes,

Comment: thank you , can you please help me ameliorate it ?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27053/70524 might help

Answer (score 1):

The following are the 6 high level stages of a typical Linux boot process.

[image: Linux boot process]

**1. BIOS**

- BIOS stands for Basic Input/Output System
- Performs some system integrity checks
- Searches, loads, and executes the boot loader program.
- It looks for boot loader in floppy, cd-rom, or hard drive. You can
  press a key (typically F12 of F2, but it depends on your system)
  during the BIOS startup to change the boot sequence.
- Once the boot loader program is detected and loaded into the memory,
  BIOS gives the control to it.

So, in simple terms BIOS loads and executes the MBR boot loader.

**2. MBR**

- MBR stands for Master Boot Record.
- It is located in the 1st sector of the bootable disk. Typically
  `/dev/hda`, or `/dev/sda`
- MBR is less than 512 bytes in size. This has three components 1)
  primary boot loader info in 1st 446 bytes 2) partition table info in
  next 64 bytes 3) mbr validation check in last 2 bytes.
- It contains information about GRUB (or LILO in old systems). So, in
  simple terms MBR loads and executes the GRUB boot loader.

**3. GRUB**

- GRUB stands for Grand Unified Bootloader.
- If you have multiple kernel images installed on your system, you can
  choose which one to be executed.
- GRUB displays a splash screen, waits for few seconds, if you don’t
  enter anything, it loads the default kernel image as specified in the
  grub configuration file.
- GRUB has the knowledge of the filesystem (the older Linux loader LILO
  didn’t understand filesystem).

Grub configuration file is

`/boot/grub/grub.conf` (`/etc/grub.conf` is a link to this). The following is sample `grub.conf` of CentOS.

```
#boot=/dev/sda
default=0
timeout=5
splashimage=(hd0,0)/boot/grub/splash.xpm.gz
hiddenmenu
title CentOS (2.6.18-194.el5PAE)
          root (hd0,0)
          kernel /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-194.el5PAE ro root=LABEL=/
          initrd /boot/initrd-2.6.18-194.el5PAE.img
```

As you notice from the above info, it contains kernel and initrd image.
So, in simple terms GRUB just loads and executes Kernel and initrd images.

**4. Kernel**

- Mounts the root file system as specified in the “root=” in grub.conf
  Kernel executes the `/sbin/init` program

  Since init was the 1st program to be executed by Linux Kernel, it has the process id (PID) of 1. Do a `ps -ef | grep init` and check the pid.
  initrd stands for Initial RAM Disk.
- `initrd` is used by kernel as temporary root file system until kernel
  is booted and the real root file system is mounted. It also contains
  necessary drivers compiled inside, which helps it to access the hard
  drive partitions, and other hardware.

**5. Init**

- Looks at the `/etc/inittab` file to decide the Linux run level.
- Following are the available run levels
- halt
- Single user mode
- Multiuser, without NFS
- Full multiuser mode
- unused
- X11
- reboot

  Init identifies the default initlevel from `/etc/inittab` and uses that to load all appropriate program.
- Execute ‘grep initdefault `/etc/inittab` on your system to identify
  the default run level

  If you want to get into trouble, you can set the default run level to 0 or 6. Since you know what 0 and 6 means, probably you might not do that.
  Typically you would set the default run level to either 3 or 5.

**6. Runlevel programs**

- When the Linux system is booting up, you might see various services
  getting started. For example, it might say `starting sendmail …. OK`.
  Those are the runlevel programs, executed from the run level
  directory as defined by your run level.
- Depending on your default init level setting, the system will execute
  the programs from one of the following directories.

  - Run level 0 – `/etc/rc.d/rc0.d/`
  - Run level 1 – `/etc/rc.d/rc1.d/`
  - Run level 2 – `/etc/rc.d/rc2.d/`
  - Run level 3 – `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d/`
  - Run level 4 – `/etc/rc.d/rc4.d/`
  - Run level 5 – `/etc/rc.d/rc5.d/`
  - Run level 6 – `/etc/rc.d/rc6.d/`
- Please note that there are also symbolic links available for these
  directory under `/etc` directly. So, `/etc/rc0.d` is linked to
  `/etc/rc.d/rc0.d`.
- Under the `/etc/rc.d/rc*.d/` directories, you would see programs that
  start with S and K.
- Programs starts with S are used during startup. S for startup.
- Programs starts with K are used during shutdown. K for kill.
- There are numbers right next to S and K in the program names. Those
  are the sequence number in which the programs should be started or
  killed.
- For example, S12syslog is to start the syslog deamon, which has the
  sequence number of 12. S80sendmail is to start the sendmail daemon,
  which has the sequence number of 80. So, syslog program will be
  started before sendmail.

Update:

Many of modern linux distros replaced **init** with **systemd** and **upstart**

**Systemd**

systemd is an init system used by some Linux distributions to bootstrap the user space and manage all processes subsequently, instead of the UNIX System V or Berkeley Software Distribution (BSD) init systems. The name systemd adheres to the Unix convention of naming daemons by appending the letter d. It is published as free and open-source software under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL) version 2.1 or later. One of systemd's main goals is to unify basic Linux configurations and service behaviors across all distributions.

As of 2015, many Linux distributions have adopted systemd as their default init system. The increasing adoption of systemd has been controversial, with critics arguing the software has violated the Unix philosophy by becoming increasingly complex, and that distributions have been forced to adopt it due to the dependency of various other software upon it, including, most notably, the GNOME 3 desktop environment.

**Upstart**

Upstart is an event-based replacement for the traditional init daemon – the method by which several Unix-like computer operating systems perform tasks when the computer is started. It was written by Scott James Remnant, a former employee of Canonical Ltd.

The traditional init process was originally only responsible for bringing the computer into a normal running state after power-on, or gracefully shutting down services prior to shutdown. As a result, the design is strictly synchronous, blocking future tasks until the current one has completed. Its tasks must also be defined in advance, as they are limited to this prep or cleanup function. This leaves it unable to handle various non-startup-tasks on a modern desktop computer elegantly, including:

- The addition or removal of USB flash drives and other portable
  storage / network devices while the machine is running
- The discovery and scanning of new storage devices, without locking
  the system, especially when a disk may not even power on until it is
  scanned
- The loading of firmware for a device, which may need to occur
  after it is detected but before it is usable

Upstart's event-driven model allows it to respond to events asynchronously as they are generated.

Hope it helps. For more details go to [thegeekstuff](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/) and [golinuxhub](http://www.golinuxhub.com/2014/03/step-by-step-linux-boot-process.html)

Comment: Of course, much of 5 and 6 are incorrect or irrelevant in modern Ubuntu, with Upstart or systemd.